Using openpyxl inside excel produces error "File not found" but works fine from Spyder
In my effort to automate the production of worksheets for students everywhere I have run into a snag. I am trying to get Python in Excel (=py) to turn an Excel table into an image and place the image into the cell where the Python code exists. openpyxl returns "File not found". This code works perfectly from Spyder and produces the following image:

This is what I am aiming for. The same code from INSIDE Excel (=py) gives me an error. Here is the code which produces the error:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Read the named range from Excel
wb = load_workbook("C:/Users/barry/Desktop/WS Generators/Stats WS Generator 2024.xlsm")
named_range = wb.defined_names['DT_1']
cells = named_range.destinations

# Get the first (and only) cell range
sheet_name, cell_range = next(cells)
sheet = wb[sheet_name]
data = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in sheet[cell_range]]

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (3,3), dpi = 400)

# Hide axes
ax.axis('off')

# Create table
table = ax.table(cellText=data, loc='center', cellLoc='center')

# Set table properties
table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(9)
table.scale(1, 1.2)

# Add borders
for cell in table._cells:
    table._cells[cell].set_edgecolor('black')
    table._cells[cell].set_linewidth(0.5)

# Show the table
plt.show()


I have tried changing \ to /.
I have tried changing single \ to double \.
I have tried "r" in front of file path. The path is correct. The folder containing the
Excel workbook is completely shared (not read only).
I have searched here (SO) and elsewhere.

Again, works when executed from Spyder, but not from Excel. Here is the traceback.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/barry/Desktop/WS Generators/Stats WS Generator 2024.xlsm'


Try r and backslashes (if you haven't tried it).

Thank you @user202311 but still file not found.

Include the traceback, in full. Format it in a [code block].


Have you tried changing the name of the XLSM to a filename without spaces in case there is some problem with Python in Excel reading such filenames? 2. I would expect an error message to specifically state such an error and notwithstanding what you have stated regarding the read-only status, but just in case, is there a possibility that there is a permissions issue preventing Excel [user] to access the file in that User's directory Have you tried reading the XLSM from another directory [or the same directory the python file is in {so the path does not need to be included}]?


Thank you @moken. I tried everything you suggested and still nothing works.

OK. I can't offer any other suggestions. Obvioulsy with file not found error it comes down to the file not being where it's presumed and often due to a relative path problem. In this scenario this seem would not be the case if indeed the path/file is "C:/Users/barry/Desktop/WS Generators/Stats WS Generator 2024.xlsm" on the PC being used. If there is some problem with Python in Excel I cannot help I don't have that feature.

Well, I got the same File not found error even for a simple open and print text file in =PY. From the MS website: “Python in Excel runs the Python code in the Microsoft Cloud … on hypervisor isolated containers built on Azure Container Instances … [and] the Python code doesn’t have access to your computer, devices, or account” (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-security-and-python-in-excel-33cc88a4-4a87-485e-9ff9-f35958278327).

openpyxl is not a supported library in Python in Excel open source libraries and python in excel also MS have used Anaconda maybe these two issues have something to do with the problem.

the Python code doesn’t have access to your computer, devices, or account is clearly what the error message is saying so try using a shared Desktop with OneDrive and see if that is a prerequisite of using Python in Excel.

Thank you @MT1.  Everything you are saying makes sense. I am working on workarounds and students everywhere thank you.
